# save data in redis with any type except string in symfony

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, redis

im using symfony and i want to make connection with my redis and insert in it values with different types except string.
i searched i found a library in symfony for that i used that this way:

```
$client = RedisAdapter::createConnection(
    'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
);
$cache = new RedisAdapter($client);
$cacheItem = $cache->getItem("testkey");
$cacheItem->set("test");
$cacheItem->expiresAfter(3600);
$cache->save($cacheItem);
```

i works but the type is string all the time ann i can specify type anyway im working with laravel too and laravel has a library Redis and you can save in redis with any data type you want.
`https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/redis`

what is the symfony solution?

Comment: Are you saying that when you insert data into Redis, no matter what the type is it always comes back as a string? Are you talking about the [Redis cache adapater](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/adapters/redis_adapter.html) from Symfony?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Redis cache adapter save values as string type. i wanted to save values in redis for example with SET type

Comment: You said "I found a library" and my question is "which library"? Is it the Redis cache adapter?